# Running an action in Gitlab CI after a branch gets merged

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration

We deploy some branches to their own environments, and afterwards those environments get deleted. We currently clean up by manually continuing the pipeline and running a cleanup job. Problem: when the job is expired this doesn't work.

Is there a way to trigger an action without it depending on some previous Gitlab CI stages, and being triggered by a branch merge?

I found that `environment:on_stop` exists, however I'm not sure how to avoid the job expiration issue.

Comment: I am also having a similar issue currently. My `environment: on_stop` action runs always. But I want it to run when the environment is stopped, meaning when branch is merged and deleted

Answer (score -1):

When you say job expiration, are you talking about the artifact? If that's the point, the job expiration default time can be set as you can see in this article: [Default artifacts expiration](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/settings/continuous_integration.html#:%7E:text=The%20default%20expiration%20time%20of,select%20Settings%20%3E%20CI%2FCD.). Or you can set it on the .gitlab-ci.yml file: [artifacts:expire_in](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifactsexpire_in)

Now if the problem is the stage timeout check this: [Timeout](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#timeout)